# Direction finding help

Tags: physics

I don't understand why this is incorrect. It's y/x times tan inverse, right?

[image]

Comment: You are close, but in the wrong quadrant. Consider the signs of $x,y\,$.

Comment: Try to consider $\tan\theta=\frac{4.49}{-4.15}$. So $\theta$ is in the $II$-quadrant.

Comment: I don't understand how it can be in Q2. I sketched the graph and it should be in Q4, just like my answer said - http://i.imgur.com/KBUYJzp.jpg

Comment: In what quadrant does the point $(-4.15,4.49)$ belongs?

Comment: it's just like how i sketched in the above pic... neg x and pos y is in Q4.

Comment: @user416503 Negative $x$ is to the *left* of the $y$ axis, so it can't possibly be in Q4.

Comment: Remember that $arctan$ and $arcsin$ always give a result in quadrants $I$ and $IV$. If the vector is actually in one of the other two quadrants you have to add $180^\circ$ or $\pi$ (if you are using radians).

Comment: Notwithstanding quadrant issues, what do you mean by `times tan inverse`? I suggest you learn the general concept of functions and function notation as soon as possible.